# Spring WS attachments- SaajSoapMessage vs AxiomSoapMessage

Tags: java, attachment, spring-ws, axiom, saaj

I have a spring web service which accepts multi-part files in requests. I was using default `SaajSoapMessageFactory` and testing my web service with `SoapUI`. When I attach multiple files with the request and when trying to access them at the service endpoint with `((SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest()).getAttachments();` I got only one attachment which has to `contentId` of first attachment.

When I found that default `SaajSoapMessageFactory` has some issue of handling attachments tried to use `AxiomSoapMessageFactory`. And now I am getting the error `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; problem accessing the parser. Parser already accessed!`

Any solution for this?

---

EDIT:
I am using `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` with `Jdom2.Element` for `@RequestPayload`. Is there any cause from it?

---

Edit:
When I have set both `payloadCaching` and `attachmentCaching` properties to `true`, `soapUI` is giving

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Try to use this config:

`<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory"
        p:attachmentCaching="true"/>`

Comment: Tried, but still the same.

Comment: I am using `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` with `Jdom2.Element` for `@RequestPayload`. Is there any cause from it?

Comment: `AxiomSoapMessageFactory` did not work for me and could solve the problem by just changing the request property `Disable multiparts` to `flase` in `SoapUI` request properties with `SaajSoapMessageFactory`.